# Css for displaying two elements side by side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get an icon to display side by side with a paragraph in Bootstrap. As you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raghavendram040/7UFe7/), the icon is appearing above the paragraph.

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span1"><p class="icon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></i></p></div>
    <div class="span11"><p class="text"><strong>Teacher Management:</strong> Here you can manage the details belongs to the teacher, by clicking the link "Teacher Management" you can view the table displaying all the teachers minimum information. The "Create New" link just above the table allow you to fill up new teacher information and the links available in the table like view, edit and delete allow you to view detailed information, to update/edit the information, to delete the information respectively.</p></div>
</div>
```

I want to position the paragraph to the right of the hand icon; how do I do that please?

Comment: Another solution, I'll also add below: http://jsfiddle.net/7UFe7/13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap's (since you're using it) col-xx-xx classes to do this.

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7UFe7/3/)

```
<div class="span1 col-xs-1">
<div class="span11 col-xs-11">
```

Bootstrap uses a 12 column system, so using 1 and 11 will make your icon 1 column and your text content the remaining 11, side-by-side.

Comment: yes this is good but i am getting more space between icon and text . how can I reduce it.

Comment: @Raghavendra You can add the `text-right` class to your icon, so `<div class="span1 text-right col-xs-1">` then use CSS to reduce the padding of your two divs. Here is an updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7UFe7/12/

Answer (score 4):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7UFe7/1/)

You can simply use:

```
.span1{
   float:left;
}
```

[**More on CSS float from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from
>   the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its
>   container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it. A
>   floating element is one where the computed value of float is not none.

As an addendum to the above, if you are already **using** **Bootstrap**, simply add the class `pull-left` to `span1` ([**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/4909/)), or use `xs-` columns ([**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7UFe7/13/))

Answer (score 1):

If you want a perfect alignment, use a table and align the text on top

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7UFe7/10/)

```
 <table id="tab">
    <tr>
        <td> div1 </td>
        <td> div2 </td>
   </tr>       
 </table>
```

Comment: I am using bootstrap , if I used table , table content is so long so when minimise the browser content will not compress.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use boot strap class

```
<div class="row-fluid col-xs-12">
            <div class="span1 col-xs-1"><p class="icon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></i></p></div>
            <div class="span11"><p class="text"><strong>Teacher Management:</strong> Here you can manage the details belongs to the teacher, by clicking the link "Teacher Management" you can view the table displaying all the teachers minimum information. The "Create New" link just above the table allow you to fill up new teacher information and the links available in the table like view, edit and delete allow you to view detailed information, to update/edit the information, to delete the information respectively.</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is good but i am getting more space betweeen two elements

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7UFe7/15/ you can use this as well just put a pull-left class